# If $\sum_{j=1}^n v_j^*v_j=1_A=\sum_{j=1}^n v_jv_j^*$ in a C* algebra A, then $\sum_{j=1}^n v_j$ is unitary.

Tags: c-star-algebras

> Let $v_1,v_2, \cdot v_n$ be partial isometries in a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$ and suppose that $$\sum_{j=1}^n v_j^*v_j=1_A=\sum_{j=1}^n v_jv_j*$$ Show that $\sum_{j=1}^n v_j$ is unitary.

This a exercise from the book "An Introduction to K-theory for $C^*$-algebras". 
If we let $p_i=v_i^*v_i$, $p_i$ is a projection as $v_i$ is partial isometry. Since
$\sum_{j=1}^n p_j=1$ we have $p_ip_j=0$ for each $i \neq j$. If I can show $v_i^*v_j=0$, then clearly $\sum_{j=1}^n v_j$ is unitary. I could not proceed from here.

Comment: Can you state which exercise this is?  I have a pdf of exercises I completed from this book, and this one might be in there.

Comment: This is problem 2.6 exercise from second chapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equality $p_kp_j=0$ is 
$$
v_k^*v_kv_j^*v_j=0.
$$
Multiply by $v_k$ on the left and $v_j$ on the right to get
$$
(v_kv_k^*)v_k\,v_j^*(v_jv_j^*)=0. 
$$
Now you use that 
$$
(v_kv_k^*)v_k=v_k. 
$$
This works for any partial isometry: if you have $v^*v=p$ and $vv^*=q$ with $p,q$ projections, then 
$$
0=p-p^2=v^*v-v^*vv^*v=v^*(1-q)v=v^*(1-q)^*(1-q)v.
$$
Then $(1-q)v=0$, which is $v=qv$.